# Local changes not reflecting changes in the browser when used docker volumes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a rails app and I use docker volumes to have the code persistent. Whenever I change anything in local the code gets reflected in the docker container, but those changes are getting reflecting in the browser. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

Right now every time there's a change in the code,  I'm restarting the containers which is not the right way to do.
Below is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - '.:/data/checklist'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: "root"
      DB_PASSWORD: "Mission2019"
      DB_DATABASE: "list"
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_HOST: db
      RAILS_ENV: production 
      RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 5
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "list"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Mission2019"
      MYSQL_USERNAME: "root"
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "redis"
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04


ENV RUBY_MAJOR="2.6" \
    RUBY_VERSION="2.6.3" \
    RUBYGEMS_VERSION="3.0.8" \
    BUNDLER_VERSION="1.17.3" \
    RAILS_VERSION="5.2.1" \
    RAILS_ENV="development" \
    GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV BUNDLE_PATH="$GEM_HOME" \
    BUNDLE_BIN="$GEM_HOME/bin" \
    BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1 \
    BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG="$GEM_HOME"

ENV PATH="$BUNDLE_BIN:$GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH"

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo
RUN echo "%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    addgroup --gid 1024 stars && \
    useradd -G stars,sudo -d /home/user --shell /bin/bash -m user
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc \
    && echo 'install: --no-document' >> /usr/local/etc/gemrc \
    && echo 'update: --no-document' >> /usr/local/etc/gemrc

USER user
RUN sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends vim make gcc zlib1g-dev autoconf build-essential libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev \
    curl htop unzip mc openssh-server openssl bison libgdbm-dev ruby git libmysqlclient-dev tzdata mysql-client
    
RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && sudo curl -fSL -o ruby.tar.gz "http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/$RUBY_MAJOR/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && sudo mkdir -p /usr/src/ruby \
    && sudo tar -xzf ruby.tar.gz -C /usr/src/ruby --strip-components=1 \
    && sudo rm ruby.tar.gz

USER root
RUN cd /usr/src/ruby \
    && { sudo echo '#define ENABLE_PATH_CHECK 0'; echo; cat file.c; } > file.c.new && mv file.c.new file.c \
    && autoconf \
    && ./configure --disable-install-doc

USER user
RUN cd /usr/src/ruby \
    && sudo make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && sudo make install \
    && sudo gem update --system $RUBYGEMS_VERSION \
    && sudo rm -r /usr/src/ruby
RUN sudo gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLER_VERSION"

RUN sudo mkdir -p "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN" \
    && sudo chmod 777 "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN" \
    && sudo gem install rails --version "$RAILS_VERSION"
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 ~/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ARG ssh_pub_key
ARG ssh_prv_key
RUN echo "$ssh_pub_key" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    echo "$ssh_prv_key" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
USER root
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
USER user
WORKDIR /data
RUN sudo mkdir /data/checklist
WORKDIR /data/checklist
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN sudo chown -R user /data/checklist
RUN bundle install
ADD . .
RUN sudo chown -R user /data/checklist
EXPOSE 3001
ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./config/docker/startup.sh"]
```

```
#! /bin/sh

# Wait for DB services

# Prepare DB (Migrate - If not? Create db & Migrate)
kill -9 `cat /data/checklist/tmp/pids/server.pid`
sh ./config/docker/prepare-db.sh

# Pre-comple app assets
sh ./config/docker/asset-pre-compile.sh

# Start Application
rails s -p 3001 -b 0.0.0.0
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "Checklist_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000', protocol: 'http' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "example.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["EMAIL"],
    password: ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: can you share startup.sh and production.rb files?

Comment: Production config does not refresh files. Use `development` for this purpose. You might have a filesystem listener issue. In your `config/development.rb` try to comment this line `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` see if it helps.

Comment: I tried commenting the mentioned line, its not working. @DannyB

Comment: Standard production-oriented Docker practice would be to delete the `volumes:`, re-run `docker build`, and delete and recreate the container when the application code changes.  You can use some combination of Bundler and `rvm` or `rbenv` to get an isolated local Ruby development environment.  You can significantly simplify that Dockerfile: do not install `sudo` or try to configure ssh access at all, and consider using the `ruby` Docker Hub image as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Rails doesn't do hot-reloading of code in production (for very good reasons including security, stability and speed), so I would consider switching over to development rails environment.

The next think to be wary of is that docker may not pick up the changes in a way that Rails will "notice" that the files have changed (even in `development`). To help with this, add a line:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

to your `production.rb` file (or `development.rb` in the case that you do switch over).