# Rails app inside docker not detecting file changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a Rails application inside a docker container. None of my file changes are being detected and auto-reloaded by Rails.

My `docker` application's main directory is mounted as a `docker` volume that maps to my host directory. In my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  my_app:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

My rails app is configured to use `ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`:

```
# config/environment/development.rb
config.cache_classes = false
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

#### What I've Tried

Inside the Rails framework:

- Here is where the logic is implemented to [check if any files are updated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.3.2/railties/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb#L223..L225). Below that you can also see where it loads the `file_watcher`
- Here is the implementation of the `FileUpdateChecker`, specifically where it checks [the maximum updated timestamp (`mtime`) for each watched path/file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2459c20afb508c987347f52148210d874a9af4fa/activesupport/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb#L129..L137)

I added print/logging statements inside the Rails gem to see if it was getting called.

When I update a file inside my application, I expect it to be detected by the file watcher but nothing is happening, and nothing gets printed.

Is this expected behavior on `docker` ? Or is there a way to hot reload while running inside a `docker` container?

Comment: Is it running in dev mode? You say you put print statements in but didn't mention if they were printing.

Comment: Yes the Rails app is running with `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'`

Comment: Can you use a non-Docker version manager like `rbenv` or `rvm` here?  This would get you a semi-isolated Ruby installation for your application, but it's still actually using your normal host filesystem, so you don't need extra tricks to make live reloading work.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue but in my case I am using `docker run` and a shared volume between the host and the container.

Comment: I solved my case, this helped me in case anyone happen to be in a similar situation like me. https://lifesaver.codes/answer/code-is-not-reloaded-in-dev-with-docker-on-os-x-25186

Comment: @Beyar that link is dead. Could you write an answer that has the information self-contained for future visitors to use? Thanks.

Comment: @ray bump can you update that link or how you solved this issue ?

Comment: I could not find an archive or cache from "lifesaver.codes" but I remember in my case, I solved it by doing the following:

`In config/environments/development.rb` I changed the following line:

`config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker`
to
`config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573768/5989038